# Apache2 proxypassreverse directive appending virtualhost port?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have been trying to setup a reverse proxy using apache 2 mod_proxy and the proxypass & proxypassreverse directives.

I am installing WSO2 Identity Server and wish to access that app using a url such as the following .

```
hxxp://myserver.domain.com/wso2/
```

The `myserver.domain.com` is accessible on the internet

Internally on my network I have set up a virtualhost running in my apache2 configuration with the following parameters:

For various reasons, port 80 is unavailable and the virtualhost must stay as :8080.

Finally, here is my virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

  <Location /wso2/>
    ProxyPass hxxps://internal.wso2.node:9443/
    ProxyPassReverse hxxs://internal.wso2.node:9443/
  </Location>

 ProxyVia On
 ProxyPreserveHost Off
 ProxyAddHeaders Off
 ProxyRequests Off
 SSLProxyEngine On
 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off

 </VirtualHost>
```

The issue:

I can use my web browser ( Firefox/Chrome) to request the http://myserver.domain.com/wso2/ resource. In my log files I see that the request does hit the apache server and the virtualhost catches the /wso2/ location.

It passes through the proxy and lands on the internal.wso2.node server. however, the product WSO2 IS preforms several redirects which, in the log files I see it requesting the resource with the port appended.

Here is the request flow

```
  hxxp://myserver.domain.com/wso2/  -> hxxps://internal.wso2.node:9443/
  REDIRECT x3
  hxxps://internal.wso2.node:8080/carbon -> 
  hxxps://internal.wso2.node:8080/carbon/admin/login.jsp

  Back to my web browser
  hxxp://myserver.domain.com:8080/wso2/carbon/admin/login.jsp
```

For some reason the apache response back appends its virtual host to the url I am requesting.

If I remove the port:8080 manually and request again the full url in the browser it will access the resource fine. However any attempt to access using only http://myserver.domain.com/wso2/ will result in redirects and the port appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you are changing also the URI when doing ProxyPass probably you will need to rewrite also the cookie

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName myserver.domain.com
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
    ProxyAddHeaders Off
    ProxyRequests Off
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    ProxyPass /wso2/ https://internal.wso2.node:9443/
    ProxyPassReverse /wso2/ http://myserver.domain.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /wso2
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain internal.wso2.node myserver.domain.com
  </VirtualHost>
```

Usually ProxyPassReverse is a bit tricky (for me at least) and probably you will need `ProxyPassReverseCookiePath`, and just in case `ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain` (to rewrite your cookies to maintain the session).